# Octobercms Stoped working (Empty response)

Tags: php, database, laravel, post, octobercms

So out of the blue octobercms stoped working, login takes forever and then fails, the same goes for loading the backend dashboard or trying to search for an update, pretty much every other interaction. You can browse the site just fine, but if you try to change and save something it just takes too long and ends up with the same error. This is the error on the console:

```
POST http://domain 0 ()                       
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've checked the php version and it's at 7.2, checked the database since its a POST failure and it all seems fine... Nothing really changed.
Any and all help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your servers error log?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i did, it seems to be clean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into the same issue, activating a positive ssl certificate seems to work. The requests where getting stuck on the server's firewall. You should contact your hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When updating the system or trying to attach some project, I was receiving an

> empty response from the server.

The problem was the firewall blocking the connection. All I did was open the port 80 to this URLs:

http://octobercms.com
http://gateway.octobercms.com

Voilá, everything started working fine to me! Hope this can help somebody.